# Alternate way for outer apply in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, outer-apply

I have a query in SQL server in which I have used outer apply. Now I want to convert it so that query can run on SQL server and MySQL also.

```
select top 5 v.sVehicleName as VehicleNo, ll.Location 
from vehicles v
outer APPLY
     (select top 1 Location 
      from location_history 
      where vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id) ll
```

I have to covert this query so I can run on both databases.

This is my tables

```
create table #vehicles (vehicle_id int, sVehicleName varchar(50))

create table #location_history ( vehicle_id int, location varchar(50), date datetime)

insert into #vehicles 
values
(1, 'MH 14 aa 1111'), 
(2,'MH 12 bb 2222'),
(3,'MH 13 cc 3333'),
(4,'MH 42 dd 4444')

insert into #location_history
values
 ( 1, 'aaa', getdate()),
 ( 1, 'bbb', getdate()),
 ( 2, 'ccc', getdate()),
 ( 2, 'ddd', getdate()),
 ( 3, 'eee', getdate()),
 ( 3, 'fff', getdate()),
 ( 4, 'ggg', getdate()),
 ( 4 ,'hhh', getdate())
```

This is query which I execute in SQL server.

```
select v.sVehicleName as VehicleNo, ll.Location 
from #vehicles v
outer APPLY
  (select top 1 Location 
      from #location_history 
      where vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id) ll
```

This is output in SQL server.

| VehicleNo | Location |
| --- | --- |
| MH14 aa 1111 | aaa |
| MH12 bb 2222 | ccc |
| MH13 cc 3333 | eee |
| MH42 dd 4444 | ggg |

I want to execute this in MySQL. and I want same output mentioned above.

Comment: can you add your table data and expected output?

Comment: in vehicle table there are two columns   vehicle_id , vehicle_name                     in location_history there are two columns vehicle_id , location , date      in location history table there can be multiple entries for each vehicle

Comment: I want first record from location history table for each vehicle which is present in vehicles table.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use LEFT JOIN instead of OUTER APPLY. like that:

```
select top 5 v.sVehicleName as VehicleNo, ll.Location 
from vehicles v
left join
     (
     select vehicle_id, min(Location) as Location
     from location_history 
     group by vehicle_id
     ) ll 
on ll.vehicle_id = v.vehicle_id
```

Comment: location is varchar . how can we apply max on location. I have checked your query but it is giving wrong output.

Comment: max(x) finds last value in alphabetical ordered set of strings and min(x) finds first value. If column [LOCATION] in [location_history] table is ascending ordered you can use min(Location) instead of "top 1 Location".

Comment: it seems in [location_history] each  [vehicle_id] has many unordered [Location]. in this case my solution is wrong. This is only for ordered column. I don't know if there is solution to convert your query in mysql without changing meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If you want first record from location history table for each vehicle which is present in vehicles table,
then you can use `cross join.`

see below e.g

```
create table #location (vehicle_id int, vehicle_name varchar(50))

create table #lochistory ( vehicle_id int, location varchar(50), date datetime)



insert into #location 
values
(1, 'car'), 
(2,'bus'),
(3,'auto'), 
(4,'jeep')

insert into #lochistory
values
 ( 1, 'india', getdate()),
 ( 1, 'usa'  , getdate()),
 ( 2, 'india', getdate())



select *from #location l
cross join
(
 select top 1 * from #lochistory 
)b
```

the output will be as below.

```
vehicle_id  vehicle_name    vehicle_id  location    date
1           car             1           india       2016-04-13 05:21:57.650
2           bus             1           india       2016-04-13 05:21:57.650
3           auto            1           india       2016-04-13 05:21:57.650
4           jeep            1           india       2016-04-13 05:21:57.650
```